# Facebook Developer canvas height settings having no effect?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I noticed that Facebook added a place to explicitly set the height of the canvas in the development app. This was very exciting news! Unfortunately what I've found during my experimentation with it is that it seems to do pretty much nothing. Am I misunderstanding what this box does (sets the default height of your app) or is there more to getting it working than just setting this value? thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a JS Method that can help you 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Ideally you would call this after your page has loaded, it will take care of the scroll bar issue, and allow your app to get to the proper size.

Comment: Yeah this is how I've always done it in the past, what I was curious about is why have the settable box at all if you're still going to require the use of setSize?

Comment: Honestly I am not quite sure. I ask myself those questions all the time when developing for FB. Poor documentation and random things that really don't do much...

Comment: lol fair enough, it is what I have learned in the last year or so as well.